# How do I migrate from rollup-plugin-typescript to @rollup/plugin-typescript?

Tags: typescript, rollupjs

I have a lerna repo with several rollup projects that are working great with rollup-plugin-typescript, but in the interest of staying updated, I'm trying to migrate to @rollup/plugin-typescript, but it's proven to be very difficult so far. Here's the first error I got:

```
Error: @rollup/plugin-typescript: Rollup 'dir' option must be used when Typescript compiler option 'declarationDir' is specified.
```

Um, okay, why? I can't find any explanation about this and it's not a requirement with the old plugin. Fine, I add `output.dir`, and now I get this:

```
Error: You must set either "output.file" for a single-file build or "output.dir" when generating multiple chunks.
```

Well, I *was* setting `output.file` since I have a single-file build, but apparently that wasn't valid. Okay, I drop `output.file`, and now I get this:

```
Error: @rollup/plugin-typescript: Path of Typescript compiler option 'declarationDir' must be located inside Rollup 'dir' option.
```

What? Why? I don't see any reason why this needs to be true, especially since my current build puts the output and typings in sibling directories and it's totally fine. Again, seemingly no documentation about why this is required now. Okay, fine, I move one directory inside the other. Now I'm getting this:

```
error TS5055: Cannot write file '<package>/dist/typings/src/index.d.ts' because it would overwrite input file.
error TS5055: Cannot write file '<package>/dist/typings/src/lib.d.ts' because it would overwrite input file.
error TS5055: Cannot write file '<package>/dist/typings/test/fixtures.d.ts' because it would overwrite input file.
error TS5055: Cannot write file '<package>/dist/typings/test/lib.spec.d.ts' because it would overwrite input file.
```

And that's where I'm at now. Why are the requirements for this plugin so different than the previous one? Some of them seem arbitrary and the overall process is pretty painful. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: When providing question to SO, it's a good idea to include your configuration files. Otherwise strangers have no idea where to help. At minimum, you should share `rollup.config.js` and `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Wow, I forgot I posted this. TBH, I've bailed on all the tech mentioned here. Rush is a million times better than Lerna, and esbuild is a million times better than Rollup. Happy I don't have to deal with these plugins ever again.